# Xcode: Cannot create a delegate Outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

This is an Objective-C app and I'm working with Xcode 14. I'm trying to migrate deprecated UIWebView to WKWebView and I've already replaced all UIWebView references in code by WKWebView, but I'm stuck in the storyboard part (bear in mind I'm new to iOS development).

What I'm trying to do is to add a WKWebView to the SB, then replicate all properties of the current UIWebView and finally remove the UIWebView.

In the following screenshot you'll see in the right pane of the Storyboard that the current UIWebView has a delegate outlet:

[image: Here you'll see a delegate outlet in UIWebView]

But I don't know hot to replicate this delegate outlet in the WKWebView that is below. I have to say I don't k ow what is a delegate in this context exactly, but I'm just trying to replicate properties of the current WebView.

How to create a delegate outlet for the WKWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your WKWebView an outlet connection for an outlet that it actually has. A WKWebView does not have a delegate property. Therefore it does not have a delegate outlet.

> What I'm trying to do is to add a WKWebView to the SB, then replicate all properties of the current UIWebView and finally remove the UIWebView.

Well, stop trying to do that. A WKWebView is very different from a UIWebView. You should not look to "replicate" anything about a UIWebView using a WKWebView. Use the WKWebView *as a WKWebView*.

For one thing, all your code interactions with this view will have to be rewritten completely. You cannot just slot the WKWebView in place of the UIWebView as if they were just two names for the same thing.

Comment: An excelent explanation @matt. I'll follow your suggestion and inspect UIWebView by UIWebView.

Comment: I have unmarked the question as correct @matt because it is partially correct. I kept investigating and WKWebView DO has delegates. The most common is WKNavigationDelegate (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate?language=objc). But I don't know how to link it to the WKWebView in the storyboard, and I'm not being able to make didFinishNavigation to trigger. Maybe you can help me in my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586720/objective-c-wkwebview-didfinish-not-triggering-when-webview-finishes-loading?noredirect=1#comment131662637_74586720

Comment: I did not say it doesn't have delegates. It has two delegates. But neither of them is called `delegate`. Which is what you asked and is what I answered. Moreover I told you to consider WKWebView as WKWebView and not as a drop-in substitute for UIWebView. Which was correct and in fact is what you did. "Maybe you can help me in my other question" Not after you took away my motivation to do so, no.

Comment: Ok, sorry @matt, I reverted the correct answer maybe too quickly, but it was expecting to receive more help. I thought that if new readers see the question marked as correct would prevent them to post anything. Given your explanations, and even you continue helping me or not, I'll revert it again. Sorry, maybe it was a mistake, but my only intention was to get more help.

Comment: Just look at the question you asked. You wanted to "replicate all properties of the current UIWebView". I told you you couldn't do that and shouldn't try. And I was right, and you _followed_ my advice and _benefitted_ from it, thus reaching the further stage you are at now. "but my only intention was to get more help" Indeed. That is what asking another question does. The fact that you now have another question does not make my answer to your first question wrong.

Comment: You are completely right @matt, that's why I said sorry because I think it was a hasty decision and reverted it again. Not only I agree with you, but also appreciate your help. Said that, I think what I did it shouldn't be considered so important to prevent you to keep helping me.

Comment: This is getting very personal and seems to me to rest upon a misunderstanding of what Stack Overflow is.