# Objective-C WKWebView: didFinish not triggering when WebView finishes loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

My app is Objective-C, and I'm migrating little by little, so I need help with Objective-C, not Swift.

I'm migrating UIWebView to WKWebView and having problems to make didFinish to work.

This the class where I use the WebView, TMAnswerView:

```
#import "TMAnswerView.h"
#import "TMConsts.h"
#import "TMPersistanceManager.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface TMAnswerView () <WKNavigationDelegate>
//UIWebViewDelegate
@end

@implementation TMAnswerView.m

-(void)customInit{
        
}

-(void)setAnswer:(TMAnswerModel *)answer{
    
    _answer = answer;
    
    float font = 17;
    NSNumber *type = [TMPersistanceManager fetchObjectForKey:PERSettingsFontSize];
    if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType1]){
        font = font * 0.75;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType3]){
        font = font * 1.25;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType4]){
        font = font * 1.5;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType5]){
        font = font * 2;
    }
    
    NSString *htmlBody = [TMUtils getHTMLStringForMath:[answer.answer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$$" withString:@"$"] andFontSize:(int)font];
    
    [_answerWebView loadHTMLString:htmlBody baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]]];
    _answerWebView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-8,0,-8);
    
}

#pragma mark - click listeners

- (IBAction)onCheckButton:(id)sender {
    if(_viewControllerType != TMMainTestViewConstrollerTypeDoTest){
        return;
    }
    _checkButton.selected = !_checkButton.selected;
    if(_delegate){
        [_delegate onCheckChanged:_answer];
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
    [self setWebViewHeight];
}

//-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(WKWebView *)webView{
//    [self setWebViewHeight];
//}

-(void) setWebViewHeight{
    CGSize fittingSize = [_answerWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    _heightOfWebView.constant = fittingSize.height;
}

@end
```

Here I've replaced UIWebView delegate by WKNavigationDelegate. I have to mention that is working fine with the old webViewDidFinishLoad of the UIWebView.

TMAnswerView.h:

```
#import "TMCustomView.h"
#import "TMAnswerModel.h"
#import "TMMainTestViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@protocol TMAnswerViewProtocol <NSObject>

-(void) onCheckChanged:(TMAnswerModel*) answer;

@end

@interface TMAnswerView : TMCustomView

@property (nonatomic, strong) TMAnswerModel *answer;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *answerWebView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightOfWebView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TMAnswerViewProtocol> delegate;

@property (nonatomic) TMMainTestViewConstrollerType viewControllerType;
-(void) setWebViewHeight;

@end
```

And finally in the storyboard I've added a WebKitView element in replacement of the old UIWebView.

I also tried with didFinishNavigation to no avail.

I checked this next page as reference:

[WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview?language=objc)

Is there anything wrong in my code? How can I make the didFinish event trigger?

### Edit 1

I also tried:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation{
    [self setWebViewHeight];
}
```

to no avail.

### Edit 2

This is the class where the WKWebView is load, TMQuestionView:

```
#import "TMQuestionView.h"
#import "TMColors.h"
#import "TMDBManager.h"
#import "TMConsts.h"
#import "TMAnswerModel.h"
#import "TMAnswerView.h"
#import "TMViewUtils.h"
#import "TMPersistanceManager.h"
#import "TMImagePreviewView.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface TMQuestionView () <TMAnswerViewProtocol, WKNavigationDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *answersView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *webviewHeight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewForLoading;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *loadingView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webviewExplanations;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *webviewExplanationsHeight;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isExplanationsVisible;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *images;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tempic;

@end

@implementation TMQuestionView

-(void)customInit{
    
    [[CSLoadingManager sharedManager] addLoadingViewToView:_viewForLoading withColor:TMBaseColor(1)];
    _images = [NSMutableArray new];
    
}

-(void)setQuestion:(TMQuestionModel *)question{
    _question = question;
    
    float font = 17;
    NSNumber *type = [TMPersistanceManager fetchObjectForKey:PERSettingsFontSize];
    if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType1]){
        font = font * 0.75;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType3]){
        font = font * 1.25;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType4]){
        font = font * 1.5;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType5]){
        font = font * 2;
    }
    
    [_images addObjectsFromArray:[TMUtils getImagesFromQuestion:question.question]];
    [_images addObjectsFromArray:[TMUtils getImagesFromQuestion:question.instructions]];
    
    NSString *htmlString = question.question;
    if(question.instructions.length > 0 && ![question.instructions isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
        htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<br/>%@", question.instructions, question.question];
    }
    NSString *htmlBody = [TMUtils getHTMLStringForMath:htmlString andFontSize:(int)font];
    htmlBody = [htmlBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<center>" withString:@"<p style='text-align:center;'>"];
    htmlBody = [htmlBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</center>" withString:@"</p>"];

    _tempic = htmlBody;
    
    [_webView loadHTMLString:htmlBody baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]]];
    _webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-8,0,-8);
    _answersView.hidden = YES;
    
    [[TMDBManager sharedManager] getAnswersForQuestion:_question completition:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        
        NSArray *temp = [dict objectForKey:DBReturnAnswers];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"answerNumber" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        self->_answers = [temp sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        [self setViewAnswers];
    }];
    
}

-(void) setExplanations{
    _isExplanationsVisible = YES;
    float font = 17;
    NSNumber *type = [TMPersistanceManager fetchObjectForKey:PERSettingsFontSize];
    if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType1]){
        font = font * 0.75;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType3]){
        font = font * 1.25;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType4]){
        font = font * 1.5;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType5]){
        font = font * 2;
    }
    NSString *htmlString = _question.explanation;
    NSString *htmlBody = [TMUtils getHTMLStringForMath:htmlString andFontSize:(int)font];
    [_webviewExplanations loadHTMLString:htmlBody baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]]];
    _webviewExplanations.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-8,0,-8);
}

-(void)setRecordAnswer:(TMRecordAnswerModel *)recordAnswer{
    _recordAnswer = recordAnswer;
}

-(void) setViewAnswers{
    int i = 0;
    
    float font = 17;
    NSNumber *type = [TMPersistanceManager fetchObjectForKey:PERSettingsFontSize];
    if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType1]){
        font = font * 0.75;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType3]){
        font = font * 1.25;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType4]){
        font = font * 1.5;
    }else if([type isEqual:SettingsFontSizeType5]){
        font = font * 2;
    }
    
    for(TMAnswerModel *item in _answers){
        
        TMAnswerView *view = [[TMAnswerView alloc] init];
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [_answersView addSubview:view];
        [[view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_answersView.leadingAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
        [[view.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_answersView.rightAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
        if(i == 0){
            [[view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_answersView.topAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
        }else{
            UIView *lastView = [[_answersView subviews] objectAtIndex:i-1];
            [[view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:lastView.bottomAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
        }

        view.answer = item;
        view.delegate = self;
        view.viewControllerType = _viewControllerType;
                
        if(_recordAnswer){
            if(item.isCorrect == 1){
                if([_recordAnswer.selectedAnswerId isEqualToString:item.answerId]){
                    [view.checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }else{
                    [view.checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked_gray"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }else{
                if([_recordAnswer.selectedAnswerId isEqualToString:item.answerId]){
                    [view.checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_error"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
        }


        i++;
        
        if(i == [_answers count]){
            [[view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_answersView.bottomAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
        }
    }
}

-(void)onCheckChanged:(TMAnswerModel *)answer{
    for (TMAnswerView *item in [_answersView subviews]){
        if(![item.answer isEqual:answer]){
            if(item.checkButton.selected){
                item.checkButton.selected = NO;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation{
    [self setHeightOfWebView];
}

//-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(WKWebView *)webView{
//    [self setHeightOfWebView];
//}

-(TMAnswerModel*) getSelectedAnswer{
    for (TMAnswerView *item in [_answersView subviews]){
        if(item.checkButton.selected){
            return item.answer;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void) setHeightOfWebView{
    _viewForLoading.hidden = YES;
    _loadingView.hidden = YES;
    CGSize fittingSize = [_webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    _webviewHeight.constant = fittingSize.height;
    _answersView.hidden = NO;
    
    for(UIView *item in [_answersView subviews]){
        if([item isKindOfClass:[TMAnswerView class]]){
            [((TMAnswerView*) item) setWebViewHeight];
        }
    }
    
    if(_isExplanationsVisible){
        CGSize fittingSizeExplanations = [_webviewExplanations sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        _webviewExplanationsHeight.constant = fittingSizeExplanations.height;
    }

}

- (IBAction)onButtonAboveWebViewClicked:(id)sender {
    if([_images count] > 0){

        TMImagePreviewView *view = [[TMImagePreviewView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kAppWidth, kAppHeight)];
        [view setImages:_images];
        [[[self superview] superview] addSubview:view];
        [view fadeIn];
        
    }
}

- (IBAction)onButtonTemp:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:sender];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[sender superview]];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    
    
    long htmlLength = _tempic.length;
    
    
    long heightOfWebView = _webView.frame.size.height;
    
    double percentTouch = (double)touchPoint.y / (double)heightOfWebView;
    
    
    int index = 0;
    
    for(NSString *imageStr in _images){
        NSString *match = [[imageStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] objectAtIndex:1];
        NSRange rangeOfImage = [_tempic rangeOfString:match];
        
        double percentText = (double) rangeOfImage.location / (double)htmlLength;

        if(percentText > percentTouch){
            break;
        }
        index++;
        
    }
    
    NSLog(@"STOP");
    
}

@end
```

Comment: You have to use the correct method signature for it to work. There is no such delegate method as `- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didFinish:(WKNavigation *)navigation`. Use the correct name (see the documentation) and it will work. You're close but not quite right.

Comment: It's funny because you don't explain me how to do it @HangarRash. It is supposed that if I'm asking is because I don't know how to do it. I'm sure something could be wrong, but don't know what. I've already checked the documentation, but I'm new to iOS development and doing my best. Could you please explain me how to do it instead of leading me to the documentation? Thanks for replying, though.

Comment: I was trying to give you hint so you could see the issue yourself. It's a better way to learn. Look at the documentation. What is the full name of the delegate method shown in the documentation? Compare that with what you put in your code. It's a small but important difference. Look at it word by word as if you've never seen it before. It's tough to proof-read your own work because you keep seeing what it is supposed to be instead of what is actually is.

Comment: Here's some more suggestions. 1) Copy and paste the method from the documentation next to your code to see the difference. 2) Use Xcode's code completion to let it enter the signature for you to avoid making simple mistakes like this one.

Comment: OK, your latest edit now shows the correct method. Is it not being called? Are any of the other navigation delegate methods being called? Did you set the navigation delegate?

Comment: Ok @HangarRash, I appreciate that you were trying to make me to learn. I'm new to iOS, and really want to learn. What does "set the navigation delegate" means? I've only set this so far: interface TMAnswerView () <WKNavigationDelegate>
Is there anything else I'm missing? For the moment I only need the didFinishNavigation to fire, and it's not firing.

Comment: Please, see my last edit @HangarRash.

Comment: You need to set the `navigationDelegate` property of your `WKWebView` outlet. You should connect that property in the storyboard.

Comment: I was trying to do that @HangarRash, but I don't know how. Check this question I've posted right before this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585307/xcode-cannot-create-a-delegate-outlet/74586259#74586259

Comment: To add some explanation to @HangarRash : WKWebView has 2 delegates : one named "UIDelegate" the other named "navigationDelegate".

Comment: Thanks for the add @Ptit Xav. Do you have any idea on why I cannot make didFinishNavigation to trigger? HangarRash said I have to link the delegate to the WKWebView in the StoryBoard, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: May be you can add this in TMAnswerView.setAnswer : «_answerWebView.navigationDelegate = self;» . BTW I would suggest you look at some iOS course to learn how to organise you classes between view , controller and models : seems a little mixed up and may be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Dear @Ptit Xav, thanks for your help. This a an old app I haven't programmed myself, I developed the Android version and paid for the iOS one, but again, it's quite old, and I know I have to migrate to Swift ASAP. This is in my plans, that's why I've already started a Swift course, but meanwhile I have a to do a little of maintenance of what we currently have. I'll try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: You were completely right @Ptit Xav, _answerWebView.navigationDelegate = self; did the job, so please write it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I added the answer. Goodluck for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can add this in TMAnswerView.setAnswer :

```
-(void)setAnswer:(TMAnswerModel *)answer {
    ...
    // set self as navigationDelegate for the webView
    _answerWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
    
    [_answerWebView loadHTMLString:htmlBody...
...
```